# Active admin customize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is there a way to exclude one or two fields in show page, instead of writing all the fields in a do block

```js
Instead of this,

show do 
    attributes_table :email,:user_name,:reset_password_token, :reset_password_sent_at ,:remember_created_at, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at,:current_sign_in_ip,:last_sign_in_ip,
  end
```

I need,Something like this. only field to exclude.

```js
show do 
  (exclude_field) :id  
end
```

Instead of writing these all I just want to remove id field from it.Any easier way to do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have modified my answer pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [active admin issue link](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/403)

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    default_fields :email, :user_name, :reset_password_token
end
```

Comment: I want only one field to exclude, the id field. But dont want to write all other fields.